# What does '0U' mean in apache's error-log?

Tags: apache

Recently, in my apache's error-log, I found a lot of lines like this :

```
[Mon Sep 12 12:34:56 2011] [error] [client ***.***.***.***] 0U, referer: http://www.***.com/
```

"`www.***.com`" is my domain name. What does '0U' mean? Responses' code corresponding to the some of the error requests are 416. My apache's version is 2.2.14. Can someone tell me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might get better results on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: 0U here is the "real error message" from apache. But it can come from the cgi or php module, etc. Do you have some more details, or the related access.log records?

Comment: I use apache+mod_jk+tomcat6 to build my website.The apache is the front end server, so there is no cgi or php module. "2011-09-12 12:34:56 218.85.19.63 "GET /site/public/stylesheets/i.css HTTP/1.1"  550 416 687 590 "http://www.9e.cn/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Wi
ndows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ) AppleWebKit/534.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Maxthon/3.0 Safari/534.12" is the corresponding access log. Note that the "416" is the http response code. But not all the error requests corresponding response code is 416. Access log's format is "%{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}t %h \"%r\" %q %D %>s %I %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\".